A320 Level change autothrust variable speed
Have some questions I'd like to get a better understanding:

assuming at Vmax 32000 feet, autothrust on but speed selected at 340 knots or vmax on a320, and I get asked to climb quiclly at 35000 ft due to weather or any other reason. How to handle that without getting overspeed? Should I decrease speed and keep AP and Autothrust on? Autothrust mct or toga?What's the best approach?
same as above but on case of TA/RA to climb, meaning AP needs to be off.
on climb aftet takeoff before reaching TOC, if I need to climb much faster at my TOC, should I manually reduce speed and then increase vs? What about autothrust setting and whether it should be left on or off?


I assume this is flight simulator as most of this would be addressed during your type rating course, so the validity of my answer is depending on the fidelity of your simulation.

at high altitude you should not be able to fly Vmax because the speed is limited by mach number. But as a general rule you will not have a problem with overspeeding as you climb. So keep AP and ATHR on as you climb. AP will keep the selected speed as you climb. You can increase your climb rate momentarily by reducing your speed slightly. With MCT or TOGA autothrust will disconnect and you will not get any additional thrust beyound CLB at high altitude anyways.
If you get overspeed warning during climb while maintaining airspeed (like Vmax) it is because you are exceeding the MMO (Mach .82) during climb. Correct technique is to keep constant airspeed as you climb (around 300kts) until your mach number reaches planned crusing speed (around M.78) and then fly constant Mach number and let the indicated speed decay.

In TCAS RA both AP and flight director must be switched off but ATHR should be kept on. This forces ATHR into speed mode (indicated by ”MACH” or ”SPEED” on the top left corner of the PFD)
As you manouver, the ATHR will adjust the thrust to maintain current speed.

You get up quickest by using CLB or OP CLB mode with ATHR on. The climb rate depends on your airspeed. You get the steepest climb with green dot speed or fastest climb with Vy which is slightly higher, around 270kts or so depending on the weight. Momentarily you can increase climb rate by reducing airspeed but from takeoff to cruising altitude stick to Vy speed. This also correlates more or less with managed speed with Cost Index 0.



If you haven't read it, you might be interested in the NTSB report on the CRJ200 Pinnacle Airlines service ceiling incident where they stalled the thing out with a double flameout, eventually deadsticking behind some houses a couple miles short of the airport. For reasons nobody can fathom, they did the last several thousand feet of the climb in VS mode, basically forcing a zoom to get to FL410 and finding themselves there on the back side of the PC, the AP holding the alt as the speed bled off until the shaker went off and all hell broke loose. Then they lied to ATC about their situation.

@JohnK Luckily the flight envelope protections on the A320 should prevent such a situation here (not that I'd recommend trying such shenanigans).

@Bianfable Well, Airbus might prevent the consequences. It will not prevent stupidity.

@busdriver Much was made of taking it to FL410, the SS. The 200 when heavy doesn't much like to go above FL370 or so.  But the airplane was on a ferry and was empty. Had they let it climb in Mach mode and let it take its time and paid attention to their energy, they'd have been fine. The introduction of high altitude stall recovery in sim training, with the aggressive push over to dive instead of teasing it on the edge of shaker you do when low (non FBW), was the direct result of that incident. Lots of pilots didn't understand that the upper FLs are a very dangerous place.

@Bianfable Watching enough of Mentour's vids, I was surprised at how many incidents were seemingly made worse by the automation, because the crew were saturated, weren't aware of all of the ins and outs of the system, and there thus surprised, when, say, the  thrust levers start moving unexpectedly on a missed b/c some mode was mis-selected in all the confusion. I often wonder where the automation should stop.

Hi there thanks so much. Sorry I'm not a pilot and indeed for sim purposes. But if for instance you have already reached alt* at 32000 feet cruising at 0.80 mach assuming you had a C.I 100. Then if you're expected to climb rapidly to 35000 feet, how you do that without exceeding speed limit?reducing the speed would it not take you longer to climb?

Is it good to say that there might different resolution actions for FL change depending on whether you are climbing, i.e THR Climb, or whether you are already at cruising altitude, ALT*, i.e SPEED mode? If so can you summarize the actions for these 2 scenarios, i.e climbing and when already in cruise? Also if your  cruise Level is low say 15000 ft, does that change anything if you need to climb fast? What about for descending before TOD? Are these rules reversed?

@RO Well, usually there is not much you can do when climbing from 32000 to 35000 ft, ie. in high altitude. Just put the new altitude in and press the knob to activate CLB mode. This forces thrust to maximum climb thrust. If you need to expedite select a lower speed. This will trade speed to altitude while keeping engines at climb thrust. In decent to process is indeed reversed. Put the engines to idle (usually done by using on of the descent modes with AP and ATHR) and then keep your cruising Mach (f.ex. M.80) until your speed has increased to around 300kts. Then maintain that with idle power.

Thanks, and from 15000 ft at mach 0.80,  to expedite climb to 32000 ft, same I guess, not much margin right?

At 15,000' MSL and Mach 0.80, you're probably way, way above your VNE max indicated airspeed limit... Using 626 knots as the speed of sound at that altitude (standard day), 8/10ths of that is 500 knots -- yeah, your A320 isn't going to be doing that any time soon!

Ok but the question would then rather be what action is needed of asked to climb fast if asked to by ATC from 15000 ft given that I'm am already flying at max mach speed for that flight level.
